Using jontjs in a more declarative way in react, misuse of react.useEffect?
The React tutorial of joint js shows a way to use jointjs in react. The tutorial is quite limited: it is basically defining a special named div and putting all jointjs code inside.
The jointjs definition also looks quite different to standard react component definitions, really like an imperative instead of declarative solution, where I could do something along the lines of, to have a paper with a rectangle on it:
return <div>
    <Paper width={300} height={300} background={{ color: '#F5F5B5' }} cellViewNamespace={namespace}>
        <Rect x={100} y={150} width={80} height={40}/>
    </Paper>
</div>


While the idea is one thing, the implementation is where I am starting to doubt, my current prototype looks like:
export const Paper = (props: PropTy) => {
    const paperEl = useRef(null);
    const graph = useRef(new Graph({}, {cellNamespace: shapes}))

    const paper = useRef<dia.Paper|undefined>();

    const {
        children
        // ... all paper props
    } = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (graph) {

            paper.current = new dia.Paper({
                el: paperEl.current,
                model: graph.current,
                // ... remaining paper props
            });
        }


        return () => {
            if (paper.current) {
                paper.current.stopListening();
                paper.current = undefined;
            }
        };
    }, [
        graph,
        // ... paper props
    ]);

    return (
        <GraphContext.Provider value={graph.current}>
            <div ref={paperEl} />
            {children}
        </GraphContext.Provider>
    );
}


export function Rect(props: RectProps) {
    const graph = useContext(GraphContext)
    const {x, y, width, height} = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("made rect")
        const rect = new shapes.standard.Rectangle();
        rect.position(x, y);
        rect.resize(width, height);
        rect.addTo(graph);
        return () => {
            console.log("remove rect");
            rect.remove();
        }
    }, [graph, x, y, width, height]);

    return <></>
}

While this works for the simple example, this seems to be misusing the useEffect? As all logic is basically hidden in a use effect and the return isn't used at all. All the while I keep reading more and more documentation that You might not need use Effect. So is there a better "solution" to this?

I have also a second idea, where instead of directly modifying the graph in the inner components, the inner components just update a list of "elements", available as a map each render. And the "Paper" component is just responsible for rendering the map to the graph each time the paper is rerendered.
